# Brauer group of a rational variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, brauer-groups

This is a follow-up question to [this question](http://www.mathoverflow.net/questions/219045/jaffes-exact-sequence/). There and here $X$ is a normal projective rational surface over $\mathbb{C}$ with finitely generated divisor class group $\text{Cl}(X)$. My question is:

> Is the Brauer group $\text{Br}(X)$ of the **rational** surface $X$ always trivial?

This might be true and well-known in a more general setting but I can't find a good reference. Let me give some context and show how the question arose. There is an exact sequence $$0 \rightarrow \text{Pic}(X) \rightarrow \text{Cl}(X) \rightarrow \bigoplus_{x \in X^{\text{sing}}} \text{Cl}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x}) \rightarrow H^{2}(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\ast}) \rightarrow 0$$ of abelian groups. If $X$ has at most ADE singularities one obtains $$\text{Br}(X) = H^{2}(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\ast})_{\text{tor}} = H^{2}(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\ast})$$ where the first equality follows from $X$ being a normal surface (see [here](http://reh.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/~schroeer/publications_pdf/azumaya.pdf)) and the second one from $\bigoplus_{x \in X^{\text{sing}}} \text{Cl}(\mathcal{O}_{X,x})$ being a torsion group (because $X$ is ADE).

If it was true that the Brauer group is trivial in the rational case I could make more precise statements about $\text{Cl}(X)$ and $\text{Pic}(X)$.

Is there a reference for this? I'm new to this and I'm not even entirely sure if the above is right. So please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Brauer group of a rational surface with non-rational singularities will in general not be trivial. For example, this is the case for the surface obtained by blowing up $\mathbb{P}^2$ at (suitably chosen) 10 points on an elliptic curve $E$ and then blowing down the strict transform of $E$.

Comment: My answer to [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/q/201341/3753) gives an explicit example of an element in the Brauer group of Cayley's cubic surface, which has four A1 singularities.  Working out your exact sequence for that surface is a nice exercise.

Comment: Could you please stop using the notation $H^{2}(X,\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\ast})$? This is very confusing. What you mean (I suppose) is $H^{2}_{\rm ét}(X,\mathbb{G}_m)$.

Comment: @abx Sorry, I've adopted the notation from the answer of the question I have linked in the beginning. It is also used in some articles, for example in [this one](http://reh.math.uni-duesseldorf.de/~schroeer/publications_pdf/brauerk3.pdf). And yes, it is meant étale cohomology here. (Isn't $\mathbb{G}_{m}$ just the same as $\mathcal{O}_{X}^{\ast}$?)

Comment: @user269218: perhaps abx's concern is that $H^2(X, \mathcal{O}_X^{\ast})$ looks like it is supposed to depict the cohomology of, say, a quasicoherent sheaf, but $\mathcal{O}_X^{\ast}$ isn't such a thing...

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Alright, thanks for pointing it out. I'll try to make my mind up and choose one or the other notation for the future.

Comment: @user269218: the problem with the notation is that $\mathcal{O}_X^*$ doesn't really define a sheaf on the étale site.  On the other hand, $\mathbb{G}_m$ does define a sheaf (like any group scheme) and that sheaf agrees with $\mathcal{O}_X^*$ when restricted to the Zariski site.  In the article you link to, I think they're working in the complex analytic site.